# Who grabbed Brody's video in Season 1?

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

Towards the end of Season 1 of Homeland, Brody makes his suicide video and places it in a secret dead drop point.  After deciding to not go through with his suicide, he tries to recover the video only to discover it is gone and Walker is there instead.  He finishes Walker off and returns home.

In the beginning of Season 2, however, the video turns up in Beirut and is the CIA's primary bargaining chip against Brody to turn him back to their side.

However, it is unclear who exactly grabbed the video as the diplomat working for Nazir was already dead, Walker appeared to not have it, and obviously Brody did not have it.

So the question is, who grabbed it?  Are we to assume it was just some random henchman that grabbed it or even perhaps Roya?

Comment: @Keen Sorry :-p

Comment: Considering Walker died a day later it's not impossible that he picked it up and mailed it. Really though, as was already mentioned it could have been anyone. I disagree with it being a mole in the CIA though as if that was the case there would have been no pointing in having them find it on the other side of the world in Season 2 except to bring it back up. But the mole would have already had the tape, it was more than likely the mole in the CIA who released the tape again after it was reacquired. I think it's Saul but that's just me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nazir's network already had plenty of people in the country at that time, so many people could have done this.  Roya is a possibility.  The mole who has plagued the CIA for both seasons could also have done it (assuming the mole isn't Brody).  Also, the assault team that stormed the tailor's shop in season 2 were active [back in season 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good_Soldier_%28Homeland%29), we just didn't see them on screen.

Given the number of agents that Nazir already had active in the US, we don't have one specific candidate for who picked up the video.

Answer (score 5):

Though it's pure speculation, but my best guess would be Roya. She might have picked it up herself or she got it done through one of her operatives.